# jQuery - Fill form input using data from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have list of items

each one contain "title", "loc" and "add button".

When I click on "add button" I would like that the right "li" values will appear in the form below (each value have identified: "data-type=")

```
<li>
    <div class="timeline-badge">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel-pointer">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title dropdown">
                <span data-type="title">some text here</span>
            </h4>
            <p><small class="text-muted"><span data-type="loc">Rome</span></small></p>
        </div>
        <p class="mt20">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info secBtn"  data-act="new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">New Section</button>
        </p>                                        
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="timeline-badge">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel-pointer">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title dropdown">
                <span data-type="title">some text here 2</span>
            </h4>
            <p><small class="text-muted"><span data-type="loc">Milan</span></small></p>
        </div>
        <p class="mt20">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info secBtn"  data-act="new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">New Section</button>
        </p>                                        
    </div>
</li>
```

FORM:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="manageSec-model" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <form id="manageSec-form" class="modal-content" action="index.php?page=itinPage&itinID=<?PHP echo $_GET['itinID'] ?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">LOCATION</label>
                    <input type="text" name='sec_details[loc]' value="" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">TITLE</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='sec_details[title]' value="" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).on('click','.secBtn',function(e) {


        alert($(this).parents("li").find("data-type=title").val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Change You jQuery. Find the Snippet Below.

```js
$(document).on('click','.secBtn',function(e) {

  var title = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('span[data-type="title"]').html();
  var location = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('span[data-type="loc"]').html();

  jQuery('#manageSec-model').find('input[name="sec_details[loc]"]').val(location);
  jQuery('#manageSec-model').find('input[name="sec_details[title]"]').val(title);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li>
    <div class="timeline-badge">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel-pointer">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title dropdown">
                <span data-type="title">some text here</span>
            </h4>
            <p><small class="text-muted"><span data-type="loc">Rome</span></small></p>
        </div>
        <p class="mt20">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info secBtn"  data-act="new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">New Section</button>
        </p>                                        
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="timeline-badge">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel-pointer">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title dropdown">
                <span data-type="title">some text here 2</span>
            </h4>
            <p><small class="text-muted"><span data-type="loc">Milan</span></small></p>
        </div>
        <p class="mt20">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info secBtn"  data-act="new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageSec-model">New Section</button>
        </p>                                        
    </div>
</li>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="manageSec-model" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <form id="manageSec-form" class="modal-content" action="index.php?page=itinPage&itinID=<?PHP echo $_GET['itinID'] ?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">LOCATION</label>
                    <input type="text" name='sec_details[loc]' value="" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">TITLE</label>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='sec_details[title]' value="" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```